# MongoDB - mongoexport all objects in nested array

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoexport

I'm using MongoDB version `2.6.x`. And I need to export documents from a specific collection.

`mongoexport` is the tool which serves the need. However, I do not know how to export all the objects under a nested array. Below is the sample document I have.

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "field_1": "value1",
  "field_2": "value2",
  "field_array": [
    {"sub_field_1": "sub_val_1", "sub_field_2": "sub_val_2"},
    {"sub_field_1": "sub_val_1", "sub_field_2": "sub_val_2"},
    {"sub_field_1": "sub_val_1", "sub_field_2": "sub_val_2"}  
  ] 
}
```

Below is the `mongoexport` command

```
mongoexport -d db_name -c collection_name -q '{"field_array.sub_field_1": {$gte: "some_value_1", $lt: "some_value_2"}}' -fieldFile fields.txt --csv > data_report.csv
```

where, `fields.txt` has below content

```
field_array.sub_field_1
field_array.sub_field_2
```

I get data as below in the csv i.e empty fields.

```
field_array.sub_field_1,field_array.sub_field_2
,
```

However, if I specify the index value in `fields.txt` like below

```
field_array.0.sub_field_1
field_array.0.sub_field_2
```

then, I get the below data

```
field_array.sub_field_1,field_array.sub_field_2
sub_val_1,sub_val_1
```

i.e, only 1 object in the field_array is returned but not all.
But, what I need is as below

```
field_array.sub_field_1,field_array.sub_field_2
sub_val_1,sub_val_1
sub_val_2,sub_val_2
```

i.e, all objects in the field_array.

Any help?

Comment: You can run an aggregate query on your docs and then put all data present in field_array to a new collection using $out of aggregate. Then its easy for you to export the documents. Check this link.          http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Answer (score 17):

**MongoExport**

To export the property whose value is array of object then unwind the array to make single document and store in new collection then export that collection.

**For Instance**

Database   : abc
collection : xyz

```
db.xyz.aggregate([
   {$unwind: "$field_array"},
   {$project: { _id:0,field_id:"$_id",Innerfield: "$field_array", "field_1": 1,"field_2":1}},
   {$out: "aggregate_xyz"}
])
```

MongoExport syntax

```
mongoexport --host <hostname> --db <Database Name> --collection <collection Name> --csv --fields fieldname1,fieldname2 --out fileName.csv
```

Example : **Export in CSV Format**

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db abc --collection aggregate_xyz --csv --fields field_id,field_1,field_2,Innerfield.sub_field_1,Innerfield.sub_field_2 --out important.csv
```

Example : **Export in JSON Format**

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db abc --collection aggregate_xyz --fields field_id,field_1,field_2,Innerfield.sub_field_1,Innerfield.sub_field_2 --out important.json
```

To know more please visit

**$unwind**

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

**$out**

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

**$project**

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: Is there a particular reason why field_id might be required as being kept?

Comment: @micseydel It's not required, but if you want to know to which original document a specific row belongs, you have to rename the _id field so that `$unwind` stage doesn't error on duplicate _id.

Comment: Actually the `$unwind` stage doesn't error, but saving the result into a collection (`$out` stage) may cause error if `field_array` of a document had more that one elements.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that **mongoexport** can not export all elements of array, unless you specify all of them with index one by one. Of course this is unrealistic.
So you can split the array and save data into a temporary collection, then export from this new collection.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([ {
    $match : {
        "field_array.sub_field_1" : {
            $gte : "some_value_1",
            $lt : "some_value_2"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        field_array : 1
    }
}, {
    $unwind : "$field_array"
}, {
    $out : "forcsv"
} ]);

mongoexport -d db_name -c forcsv --fieldFile fields.txt --csv > data_report.csv
```

Comment: The import of the splitted collection does not work because it's impossible to add documents with the same _id.