# mongodb export from wide format to long format

Tags: mongodb, csv, export-to-csv, dataformat, database

the mongodb documents structures are like:

No1.

```
"id" : 1,
"article": "go hiking and bbq",
"category": [
   "travel",
   "hiking",
   "bbq"
]
```

No2.

```
"id" : 2,
"article": "I love cat and travel",
"category": [
   "pet",
   "cat",
   "travel"
]
```

when i use mongoexport to export it to csv format, it will give me something like:

```
id  article                 category
1   go hiking and bbq      ["travel", "hiking", "bbq"]
2   I love cat and travel  ["pet", "cat", "travel"]
```

which is "wide format" data structure

**SO, I wonder if it's possible if it's possible to export as LONG FORMAT, I want to OPEN the category array, repeat each article per category. something like:**

```
id  article                 category
1   go hiking and bbq      "travel"
1   go hiking and bbq      "hiking"
1   go hiking and bbq      "bbq"
2   I love cat and travel  "pet"
2   I love cat and travel  "cat"
2   I love cat and travel  "travel"
```

or if mongodb do not have this function, is there any tools that could help me to transfer the exported csv file from wide format to long format? thanks

==== updated, Solutions here====

thx wizard. update mongodb up to 2.6.x.
first aggregate to a new collection, then export that collect
refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378769/mongodb-mongoexport-all-objects-in-nested-array?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Reference this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378769/mongodb-mongoexport-all-objects-in-nested-array/26383060#26383060)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - mongoexport all objects in nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378769/mongodb-mongoexport-all-objects-in-nested-array)