# Make faster a read from file

Tags: java, mongodb, csv, neo4j

I'm going to pass my data from MongoDB to Neo4j. 
So, I exported my MongoDB documents in .csv. As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055504/export-an-array-in-csv-from-mongodb) I have a problem with the array uniform. 
So I wrote a java program to fix this problem. 

Here is the .csv exported from MongoDB (note the different about **uniform** array):

```
_id,official_name,common_name,country,started_by.day,started_by.month,started_by.year,championship,stadium.name,stadium.capacity,palmares.first_prize,palmares.second_prize,palmares.third_prize,palmares.fourth_prize,average_age,squad_value,foreigners,uniform
0,yaDIXxLAOV,WWYWLqPcYM,QsVwiNmeGl,7,9,1479,oYKGgstIMv,qskcxizCkd,8560,10,25,9,29,16,58,6,"[""first_colour"",""second_colour"",""third_colour""]"
```

Here is how it must be to import in Neo4j:

```
_id,official_name,common_name,country,started_by.day,started_by.month,started_by.year,championship,stadium.name,stadium.capacity,palmares.first_prize,palmares.second_prize,palmares.third_prize,palmares.fourth_prize,average_age,squad_value,foreigners,uniform.0,uniform.1,uniform.2
0,yaDIXxLAOV,WWYWLqPcYM,QsVwiNmeGl,7,9,1479,oYKGgstIMv,qskcxizCkd,8560,10,25,9,29,16,58,6,first_colour,second_colour,third_colour
```

My code works, but I have to convert 500k line of the .csv file and the program it is too much slow(it's still working after 20 minutes :/):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ConvertireCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader f;
        f=new FileReader("output.csv");

        BufferedReader b;
        b=new BufferedReader(f);

        String firstLine= b.readLine();
        int uniform = firstLine.indexOf("uniform");
        firstLine=firstLine.substring(0, uniform);
        firstLine = firstLine + "uniform.0,uniform.1,uniform.2\n";

        String line="";
        String csv="";

        while(true) {
            line=b.readLine();
            if(line==null)
                break;
            int u = line.indexOf("\"[");
            line=line.substring(0, u);
            line=line + "first_colour,second_colour,third_colour \n";
            csv=csv+line;                   
        }

        File file = new File("outputForNeo4j.csv");

        if(file.createNewFile()) {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file); 
            pw.println(firstLine + csv);
            System.out.println("New file \"outputForNeo4j.csv\" created.");
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

*How can I make it faster?*

Comment: In a first fast view I would say, check that you have enough heap and I will use StringBuilder instead Strings. You should try to find which part of the code is being too slow

Comment: this should really be on code review SE tbh

Comment: perhaps you'd be interested to work with us on feedback on the mongodb -> neo4j docs collector ? let me know michael at neo4j.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay some basic ways to improve your code:

1. Make sure that your variables got the minimal scope required. If you don't need `line` outside your loop, don't declare it outside your loop.
2. Concatenation of simple strings is in general slow. Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to speed things to there.
3. Why are you buffering the string anyway? Seems like a waste of memory. Just open the output stream to your target file and write the lines to the new file as you process them.

**Examples:**

I don't think you need a example on the first point.
For the second things could look like this:

```
...
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
while(true) {
    ...
    csv.append(line);
}
...
if(file.createNewFile()) {
    ...
    pw.println(firstLine + csv.toString());
    ...
}
```

For the third point the rewriting would be a little more extensive:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader f;
    f=new FileReader("output.csv");

    BufferedReader b;
    b=new BufferedReader(f);

    String firstLine= b.readLine();
    int uniform = firstLine.indexOf("uniform");
    firstLine=firstLine.substring(0, uniform);
    firstLine = firstLine + "uniform.0,uniform.1,uniform.2\n";

    File file = new File("outputForNeo4j.csv");
    if(!file.createNewFile()) {
        // all work would be for nothing! Bailing out.
        return;
    }

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file); 
    pw.print(firstLine);

    while(true) {
        String line=b.readLine();
        if(line==null)
            break;
        int u = line.indexOf("\"[");
        line=line.substring(0, u);
        line=line + "first_colour,second_colour,third_colour \n";
        pw.print(line);                   
    }

    System.out.println("New file \"outputForNeo4j.csv\" created.");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    b.close()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 csv=csv+line;
```

string concatenation is expensive operation. I would suggest using bufferedWriter.
something like this:

```
FileReader f;
     f=new FileReader("output.csv");

     BufferedReader b;
     BufferedWriter out;
     b=new BufferedReader(f);
     try{
      out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outputForNeo4j.csv"));
     } catch(Exception e){
        //cannot create file 
     }
     System.out.println("New file \"outputForNeo4j.csv\" created.");

     String firstLine= b.readLine();
     int uniform = firstLine.indexOf("uniform");
     firstLine=firstLine.substring(0, uniform);
     firstLine = firstLine + "uniform.0,uniform.1,uniform.2\n";

     String line="";
     String csv="";

     out.write(firstLine);

     while(true) {
         line=b.readLine();
         if(line==null)
             break;
         int u = line.indexOf("\"[");
         line=line.substring(0, u);
         line=line + "first_colour,second_colour,third_colour \n";
        out.write(line);               
     }         
        out.flush();

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Results :
test0 : Runs: 241 iterations ,avarage milis = 246
test1 : Runs: 249 iterations ,avarage milis = 118
test2 : Runs: 269 iterations ,avarage milis = 5
test3 : Runs: 241 iterations ,avarage milis = 2

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Random;

public class Tester {

private static final String filePath = "c:\\bigFile.txt";
//private static final String filePath = "c:\\bigfileNewLine.txt";

private static final int numOfMethods = 4;
private static final int numOfIter = 1000;
public Tester() throws NoSuchMethodException {
    System.out.println("Tester.Tester");

    int[] milisArr = new int [numOfMethods];
    int[] actualRun = new int [numOfMethods];

    Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    Long startMs = 0l, endMs = 0l;
    Method[] method = new Method[numOfMethods];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfMethods; i++)
        method[i] = this.getClass().getMethod("test" + i);

    int testCount = 0;
    while (testCount++ < numOfIter) {
        int testMethod = rnd.nextInt(numOfMethods);
        Method m = method[testMethod];
        try {
            System.gc();
            startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
            String retval = (String) m.invoke(null);
            endMs = System.currentTimeMillis();

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        milisArr[testMethod] += (endMs - startMs);
        actualRun[testMethod]++;
        System.out.println("Test name: " + m.getName() + " testCount=" + testCount + " Of " + numOfIter + " iteration, Total time :" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000.0 + " seconds");
    }

    System.out.println("Test Summery :");
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfMethods; i++)
        System.out.println("test" + i + " :  Runs: " + actualRun[i] + " iterations ,avarage milis = " + milisArr[i]/numOfIter);

}


public static String test0() throws IOException {
    InputStream file = getInputStream();
    StringBuffer textBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    int c;
    while ((c = file.read()) != -1)
        textBuffer.append((char) c);


    file.close();
    return textBuffer.toString();
}

public static String test1() throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new FileReader(new File(filePath));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line = br.readLine();
    String result = line;
    while (line != null) {
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
        } else {
            result = result + "\n" + line;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    reader.close();
    return result;
}


public static String test2() throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int l;

    InputStream is = getInputStream();
    StringBuffer tmpBuf = new StringBuffer();
    while ((l = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
        tmpBuf.append(new String(buf, 0, l));
    }

    is.close();
    return tmpBuf.toString();
}

public static String test3() throws IOException {
    File source = new File(filePath);
    final DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source)));
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) source.length()];
    dis.readFully(buffer);
    dis.close();
    return new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
}

private static InputStream getInputStream() {
    try {
        return new FileInputStream(filePath);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Tester();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

}