# Mongoexport - How to Export Nested Values to CSV File

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to learn mongodb. I have been reading about mongoexport, however, I've been unable to get this export to work. I have data that basically looks like the following:

```
{
    "Label1":"Value1",
    "Label2":"Value2",
    "Label3":[
        {
        "Label3a":"Value3a",
        "Label3b":"Value3b",
        "Label3c":
            {
            "Label3ca":"Value3ca",
            "Label3cb":"Value3cb",
            "Label3cc":"Value3cc"
            }
        "Label3d":
            {
            "Label3da":"Value3da",
            "Label3db":"Value3db",
            "Label3dc":"Value3dc"
            }
    "Label4":"Value4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to export values at the top level as well as deep within the nested values. I've read in other documents that using dotted notation should allow me to access these values.

The command I am trying to run looks like the following:

```
mongoexport --db database --collection collection --fields Label1,Label2,Label3.Label3c.Label3ca --query "{'_id':ObjectId('59d6b41027966f12c871c48d')}" --type=csv --out c:\temp\all_users1.csv
```

The command runs successfully and exports 1 record. I even get data back for `Label1` and `Label2`. However, I do not get back any data for `Label3.Label3c.Label3ca.`

I have tried many combinations. Basically, I have been unable to get any data back past the first level.

Can you please point me in the right direction of how to get this to work?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try  these command --fields 'Label1,Label2,Label3.Label3c.Label3ca'

Comment: Hi Hurricane, I get this output when using the dotted notation. Label1,Label2,Label3.Label3a
Value1,Value2, (I don't get a value back from the dotted notation section).

Comment: Don't use whitespaces.

Comment: I am currently looking at technotes along this line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378769/mongodb-mongoexport-all-objects-in-nested-array. Looks like I may need to aggregate data to a new collection. Seems a bit onerous just to get access to these values. I wonder if there is an easier way to do this?